# Why does passing a parameter that returns a variable but also has a println also passes the println?

Tags: java, parameters

When running this java program, I would expect the output only be the first println since the other methods, quaffle and snitch only returns integers. However, the output for this program also includes the quaffle and snitch method's println. I would expect that the println would be useless in the latter methods since they were not returned. What happened?

**The output:**

snitch: x = 4004, y = 1001  
quaffle: x = 2003, y = 1, z = 1001 
bludger: x = 1001, y = 2001, z = 2003

**The program:**

```
import acm.program.*; 
public class Hogwarts extends ConsoleProgram { 
 public void run() { 
  bludger(2001); 
 } 

 private void bludger(int y) { 
  int x = y / 1000; 
  int z = (x + y); 
  x = quaffle(z, y); 
  println("bludger: x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", z = " + z); 
 } 

 private int quaffle(int x, int y) { 
  int z = snitch(x + y, y); 
  y /= z; 
  println("quaffle: x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", z = " + z); 
  return z; 
 } 

 private int snitch(int x, int y) { 
  y = x / (x % 10); 
  println("snitch: x = " + x + ", y = " + y); 
  return y; 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `println` writes a line of output when it is invoked.  You don't need to do anything with the value it returns.  Since you invoke `println` three times, you will get three lines of output.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a mis-understanding of what the return statement means.

'return' returns the specified value to the point from where the function was called. The function is free to perform any other operations, print things to terminal, create and delete files or do anything else - those actions are not "undone" by the fact that they're not "returned" from the function.

This is called [side-effect of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 0):

No, `println` is not returned here.

This println is executed for following execution flow.

```
call bludger
 -> call quaffle
    -> call snitch
       -> print "snitch" // snitch is printed first
    -> print "quaffle"   // later quaffle
 -> print "bludger"      // and now bludger
```

Answer (score 0):

`println()` has nothing to do with return. When `println()` is invoked, it writes to output at once, then return is called. So even if the function is returned, `println()` has been executed.